# Magento URL rewrite - dynamic

Tags: url-rewrite, seo

In My Magento website, There are around 1800 URLs which follow this pattern

www.mywebsite.com/(subcategory)/brands-1/(brand)
These need to be redirected to www.mywebsite.com/brands-1/(brand)

Can any one help me how to implement this?

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: see also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7111/custom-url-rewrites